# MySQL will not run after exhausting disk space while indexing

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

After I tried to index a column in a huge table (40G) and ~5million rows, I can no longer connect to the datatbase.

[Indexing failed with this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850287/error-1114-hy000-the-table-xxx-is-full)

Later, I found out I ran out of disk space while mysql was stopped. And, now I can not get mysql run again. I tried almost everything on SO except where purging mysql/reinstalling was mentioned. Is there anything I can do to get my data back or run mysql again? Or, I could extract my tables from `ibdata1`?

Answer (score 3):

There could be about 3 things going on here...

1. You ran out of disk space.  Can you scrounge some space, even a little?
2. You cannot connect because of a socket problem.  Remove the socket and try again.
3. The attempt to add an index could have been performed in a couple of different ways.  Was the table MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  If InnoDB, was `innodb_file_per_table` ON?

In any case, look for `#sql...` files they were the tmp tables being built before "renaming" them into place.  They are useless no; remove them.

If `file_per_table` was off, then probably `ibdata1` got a lot larger in this failed operation.  This will call more a messier repair.

Since you have an old version of MySQL, I won't point out `ALTER TABLE .. ALGORITHM=INPLACE, ADD INDEX ..;`

Comment: - I resized my instance. Now I have unused 20G+.
- I'll try removing sockets and reconnect.
- The table was InnoDB. Unfortunately, `innodb_file_per_table` was off.

Thanks, I will try your suggestions in evening.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi if Rick's solution worked can you mark as chosen?